# Fundamental Group of Compact Connected Lie Group

Tags: lie-groups, homotopy-theory

A compact, connected Lie group is isomorphic to the quotient of a torus $T$ and a simply-connected, compact Lie group $J$ by a finite central subgroup $Z\subseteq T\times J$: $$G\simeq (T\times J)/Z.$$

**Main Questions**: Are we able to tell anything about $\pi_1(G)$ from $Z$ when $T$ is not the trivial group? Conversely, if $\pi_1(G)=\mathbb{Z}^n$, does that mean that we can take $Z=1$?

**Work on Problem**:
I know that if $G$ is a semi-simple Lie group ($T=1$), then $G\simeq J/Z$. Using the homotopy exact sequence for the fibration $J\rightarrow G$ with fibre $Z$, we have $$\pi_1(J)\rightarrow \pi_1(G)\rightarrow \pi_0(Z)\rightarrow \pi_0(J).$$
As $J$ is simply-connected, we have $\pi_1(G)\simeq \pi_0(J)\simeq \mathbb{Z}_{|Z|}$.

If we do the same thing for $T$ general, we have the exact sequence $$\pi_1(Z)\rightarrow \pi_1(T\times J)\rightarrow \pi_1(G)\rightarrow \pi_0(Z)\rightarrow \pi_0(T\times J).$$ Substituting in the known homotopy groups, we have $$1\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^{\mathrm{dim}(T)}\rightarrow\pi_1(G)\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{|Z|}\rightarrow 1.$$
As $G$ is a compact, connected Lie group, $\pi_1(G)$ is a finitely generated abelian group. While this tells me the rank of $G$, how can I determine the torsion of $G$?

Comment: A quick thought: $\pi_1(G) \cong H_1(G)$ by the Hurewicz theorem since $\pi_1(G)$ is already abelian. The universal coefficient theorem tells you that the torsion in $H_1(G)$ is the same as the torsion in $H^2(G)$. The long exact sequence for the pair $(T \times J, Z)$ tells you that $H^2(G)$ is isomorphic to $H^2(T \times J)$, so the torsion in here can be deduced from the low-dimensional cohomology of $J$. But $\pi_2$ vanishes for Lie groups so $J$ is actually 2-connected, so its second cohomology is trivial. So I believe this says that $\pi_1(G)$ is torsion-free?

Comment: Consider $J=\mathrm{SU}(2)$ and $Z=\{(1,\pm I)\}\simeq\mathbb{Z}_2$. Then $G\simeq (T\times J)/Z\simeq T\times \mathrm{SO}(3)$. Thus, $\pi_1(G)\simeq \mathbb{Z}^{\mathrm{dim}(T)}\times \mathbb{Z}_2$. Hence, we can have torsion.

Comment: I figured there was an easy counterexample, the final result seemed wrong. The error in the above line of reasoning is that $G = T \times J / Z$ is the quotient by the action of $Z$ on $T \times J$, not the topological quotient by the subspace $Z$ (the argument in my comment assumes the latter, oops). But, for what it's worth, you can still determine the torsion of $\pi_1(G)$ from the torsion in $H^2(G)$--I just don't know if there's a pretty and easy/general way to make that computation. Maybe Serre spectral sequence for $Z \to T \times J \to G$?